# Register-ObjectEvent for runspace in an arraylist

Tags: powershell, runspace

I am creating a runspace pool that will have multiple runspaces starting an stopping at different times.

To keep track of this all of my runspaces go into a collection.

I am trying to register an object event for each one so that I can return information from the runspace to the user in the gui.

The part where I am having problems with is here:

```
$Global:RunspaceCollection
$Global:x = [Hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})

$RunspaceCollection = @()
[Collections.Arraylist]$Results = @()

$RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1,5)
$RunspacePool.Open()

$action = {
    Foreach($Runspace in $Global:RunspaceCollection.ToArray()) {
        If ($Runspace.runspace.iscompleted){
            $results.add($runspace.powershell.endinvoke($Runspace.runspace))

            $runspace.powershell.dispose()
            $runspacecollection.remove($Runspace)
            Write-Host "I AM WORKING"
            test-return

    }
}
Function Start-PasswordReset($username) {

    $scriptblock = {
    Param($userame)
    start-sleep -Seconds 10
    $Result = "I have reset" + $username
    $result
}

$Powershell = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript($ScriptBlock).AddArgument($username)
$Powershell.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool

[Collections.Arraylist]$Global:RunspaceCollection += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{ 
    Runspace = $PowerShell.BeginInvoke() 
    PowerShell = $PowerShell

}
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $runspacecollection[0].Runspace -EventName statechanged -Action $Action
}


}
```

The code is failing on the register-objectevent line, currently I have hard coded 0 for testing, but that will be the current runspaces number in the final version. I don't know if I have made a small mistake, or have a fundamental lack of understanding of how this works, I'm open to both possibilities!

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to actually accomplish. The code as you have it posted does not work, it fails to add the New-Object to the array list for me, that must not be the complete code? Register-Object event requires an event that the object emits, so in your case the PSObject.Runspace should have a StateChanged event. Please provide a more complete code listing or a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: No it is not the complete code, I will post it when I get back in tommorow. Essentially I would be expecting the Runspace object stored in the collection to have a statechanged event, however when I check with get-member it is missing.

Comment: @BenRichards I have added the full lot. This is just a test function which doesn't actually do anything other than writing to variables & to the shell. Once it works I plan on putting it behind a gui to stop long running tasks interfering, as there will be multiple running at the same time that may take upto 2 minutes to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few issue but your main is that the StateChanged event is an event on the RunspacePool.Powershell object inside your RunspaceCollection[index] and not on the RunspaceCollection.Runspace (the custom "Runspace" property of the PSObject you have created).

Set your runspace on the Powershell object as in:

```
$powershell = [PowerShell]::Create()
$powershell.RunspacePool = $runspacePool
$powershell.AddScript($scriptBlock).AddArgument($username)
$Global:runspaceCollection += @{
    PowerShell = $powershell
    Handle     = $powershell.BeginInvoke()
}
```

And then declare your event as:

```
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $Global:runspaceCollection[0].PowerShell.RunspacePool -EventName StateChanged -Action $Action
```

After that, I don't think you intended to have the Start-Password reset function inside the "Action" function. Here is the complete code that worked for me:

```
$Global:RunspaceCollection
$Global:x = [Hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})

$RunspaceCollection = @()
[Collections.Arraylist]$Results = @()

$RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, 5)
$RunspacePool.Open()

$action = {
    Foreach ($Runspace in $Global:RunspaceCollection.ToArray()) {
        If ($Runspace.runspace.iscompleted) {
            $results.add($runspace.powershell.endinvoke($Runspace.runspace))

            $runspace.powershell.dispose()
            $runspacecollection.remove($Runspace)
            Write-Host "I AM WORKING"
            test-return
        }
    }
}

Function Start-PasswordReset($username) {
    $scriptblock = {
        Param($userame)
        start-sleep -Seconds 10
        $Result = "I have reset" + $username
        $result
    }

    $powershell = [PowerShell]::Create()
    $powershell.RunspacePool = $runspacePool
    $powershell.AddScript($scriptBlock).AddArgument($username)
    $Global:runspaceCollection += @{
        PowerShell = $powershell
        Handle     = $powershell.BeginInvoke()
    }

    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $Global:runspaceCollection[0].PowerShell.RunspacePool -EventName StateChanged -Action $Action
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback, I'll give it a go tommorow and let you know how I got on.

Comment: Sure thing! I didn't know you can do what you were doing, I learnt something too!

Comment: It seams like no one has really considered flagging results from run spaces in a way that doesn't thread lock, very annoying if your running a gui! I've only learnt about runspaces in the past week, but they have the potential to make my life lot easier once I've figured them out.

Comment: I came across this when I was trying to help you, maybe it will help. https://learn-powershell.net/2016/12/04/tracking-the-state-of-powershell-runspaces-in-a-runspacepool/

Comment: I've ran the code in both the ise and the normal console, I do seem to get statechanges for when the job is not started, however nothing for when it finishes. I've just pulled the For each loop out of the script block so I could run it and see the errors and I get a "method invocation failed because [system.object] doesn't contain a method named 'toarray'. I will have a play around and see what I can do! Also thanks for the link, that was actually one of the first ones that helped me start to understand!

Comment: Thank you for your help Ben, I ended up saving the runspaces ID to an observable collection after the job had completed. I had an event listening to that collection which cleaned up the job on completion.